# Unable to switch to a popup

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Can anybody help me out? I have an app which displays a popup as soon as the app (url) is launched. The popup contains images, text, checkbox and button.
I can able to locate the checkbox and button using firebug but when I use the same in code to handle that, it get fails and throws an error as follows:

```
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"**//div[@class='modal-dialog']/div/div/button[@type='button']/span[text()]**"}
```

I have tried with ways as follows

1. Alert-- but it is telling that not an alert
2. Frame-- `driver.switchTo().frame(0)` is passed but after that the same error as above described
3. XPath-- no use same error as above.

Note: It is an ecommerce app.
Can anybody please help me out.

Comment: do you have android app?

Comment: It is a web application, i need to automate through selenium webdriver.

Comment: can you please  share all html code of that popup and page?

Comment: Code Snippet:  <div id="overLayBoxPopup" class="overLayBoxPopup">
     <form name="frmOverageConfirm" id="frmOverageConfirm" method="POST">
      <div id="overageconfirm">
       <div id="overageconfirm_header" class="header-data">Confirm your age </div>
<div id="overageconfirm_content" class="content-data">

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the `driver.getWindowHandle()`, this method returns only the handle for current window ( your main window). If another pop-up window opens, you will need to call  `Set<String> handles = driver.getWindowHandles()` to return a list of all available handles. And then you call `driver.switchTo().window(handles.get(handles.size() - 1))`. This will switch to the last listed window handle.

Comment: Set <String>initial=driver.getWindowHandles(); returns only one string [{43169bda-89e2-4c83-ba01-b4f76e1ecdb6}]. can't switch to the same window right. After this statement I wrote driver.findElement(By.xpath(xpathexpr)).click(); which works fine. Here I don't know how it is handled, thank you anyways.